# zlib Z_DATA_ERROR inflate issue

Tags: zlib

I have this issue which is probably something simple but I cannot get around it.
I deflate with a python script (import zlib) and I do the inflate on an embedded platform using zlib version 1.2.11, January 15th, 2017.

For testing purposes, I've created a constant table in ROM, which is the deflated data created by the script.
The z_stream structure is called test_stream.

If I point the test_stream.next_in to the constant table/buffer in ROM, the inflate works fine, the data is recovered OK, no problem.

But if I copy from ROM into a RAM buffer and pass that RAM buffer to test_stream.next_in, the inflateInit(&test_stream) returns Z_DATA_ERROR (-3) and the test_stream.msg contains: " -- missing end-of-block" or "invalid code lengths set".

Obviously I've checked that the RAM buffer is copied properly from ROM.
Am I missing something here, does the RAM buffer needs some alignment or something else?
I know it seems weird but any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no alignment requirements. You must be giving it the wrong address, or not properly copying the compressed data.

Comment: Indeed a stupid error in the data copy :) Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: Late hour I guess :)